# pandas selecting and assigning using lambda

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to select certain rows from a DataFrame and apply a result from lambda from it, and I am not able to assign it correctly, either all the other columns become NaN or the DataFrame not changed at all (I believe this is related to DataFrame returning a copy, read that caveat)

Here is my DataFrame:

```
id     type               value
--------------------------------------------
 1        1                 "Store Name 1"
 2        2                 "Store Name 2"
 3        3                 123
```

the gist of it, I want to select "type" == [1,2] and run a lambda function on the value column and set it with the return value
and here is my attempt:

```
p1['value'] = p1[p1['type'].isin([1,2])]['value'].apply(
        lambda v: Store.objects.get(name=v).id
    )
```

this sets the value for types that are [1,2] but unfortunately, it also sets all the other values to NaN.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to put your "is in" logic into your lambda function, and not change any rows that don't match:

```
p1['value'] = p1.apply(lambda row: Store.objects.get(name=row.value).id if row.type in [1,2] else row.value, axis=1)
```

Comment: this does work, but it seems using pandas API would be faster. Is there a better way? that fully utilizes pandas data querying.